# xhr.upload.addEventListener load has empty xhr.responseText

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
xhr.open('put',url,false)
xhr.upload.addEventListener('load',function(e){alert(xhr.responseText)},false)
```

Why is xhr.responseText empty? When using xhr.onreadystatechange 4 xhr.responseText has data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Gert is trying to say is that you have to add the event listener to the `xhr` object, not `xhr.upload`. I'm not entirely sure why and [the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#events) isn't exactly clear. It isn't anything to do with asynchronous requests which are the default anyway.

Instead of:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function(e){ alert(xhr.responseText); }, false);
```

You must do:

```
xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e){ alert(xhr.responseText); }, false);
```

Comment: lol I actually didn't notice that I put the event listener on xhr :) But if I remember correctly xhr.open('put',url,false) also didn't work.

Comment: Made small edit and accepted this answer instead of my old one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(My old answer maybe wrong see new answer Timmmm)

I needed to set XMLHttpRequest asynchronously for it to work.

```
xhr.open('put',url,true)

xhr.addEventListener('load',function(e){alert(xhr.response)},false)
```